# Iterate in order an .EACH loop with an AJAX request inside

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I want to iterate through a list of items to save it in my database, but it is mandatory to save them in order, I mean that the last AJAX request have to be done to go to the next loop.

> As i know the EACH LOOP is synchronous but the AJAX request isn't. I can skip to the next loop with `return true` and i can break the loop with `return false`

```
$('#ListOfItems').each(function () {
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/Api/Workers/Save",
            data: JSON.stringify(ItemToSave),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                //continue to the next loop
            },

            error: function (jqXHR, status) {
                //continue to the next loop
            }

        });
        //handle the loop until the Ajax request is done

});
```

So, How can I handle the loop until I get any response from the AJAX request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Async:False` will hold the execution of rest code. Once you get response of ajax, only then, rest of the code will execute.

OR

You could use `$.ajax.then(doneCallback, failCallback )`

Comment: Should I put it as a parameter in the Ajax request like type: "POST" ?

Comment: Yes , you can add a paramater to you ajax `async: false`

Comment: Thanks, It worked well but I got a warning in **Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience**. I know that I can avoid it doing fixes in my code in the server side. Should I ignore that warning?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the **async** parameter. This one can be set as `true`or `false`.
Here is how your code should look like to make it sync.

```
$('#ListOfItems').each(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Api/Workers/Save",
        data: JSON.stringify(ItemToSave),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            //continue to the next loop
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status) {
            //continue to the next loop
        }
    });
});
```

That would be great if you could read that [post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) . Scroll down tho the async part.

> async (default: true)
>   Type: Boolean
>   By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done().

Comment: Thanks, It worked well but I got a warning: **Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience**. I know that I can avoid it doing fixes in my code in the server side. Should I ignore that warning?

Comment: Yes thats a warning. Javascript is basically asynchronous. When you make it sync you are blocking other processes to perform.